# c#-The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm new to .net development

I'm trying to fetch the data from Facebook app,when update the query I'm getting the above error on update customer details

in 'cust_date' filed and i taken in cust_date datatype is DATETIME.

so how to convert this DATETIME format to 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM'

```
    public void Customer(string Customerid)
    {
        var accessToken = "CAACEdEose0cBAMTINaTZCrm67pT6cO16KHsR3UNgOTZAGH03GHmhKozUOxEXYpL3ZB9pfbFWm4Oj2VMVy8xMf5vXMpFtY6LZm2Hej0WmrHPlwk7pWyibf9gXbCaDBoIih26nRqffAfwZD";
        var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        string clientfeed = client.Get(Customerid).ToString();

        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(clientfeed);



        string custid = obj["id"].ToString();
        string name = obj["name"].ToString();
        string fst_name = obj["first_name"].ToString();
        string lst_name = obj["last_name"].ToString();
        string link = obj["link"].ToString();
        string[] splitlink = link.Split('/');
        if (splitlink[3].StartsWith("profile"))
        {
            splitlink[3] =name.ToString();
            link = splitlink[0] + '/' + splitlink[1] + '/' + splitlink[2] + '/' + splitlink[3];
        }
        string gender = obj["gender"].ToString();
        string cust_updated_time = obj["updated_time"].ToString();
        string abctime = cust_updated_time.Substring(0, cust_updated_time.ToString().Length - 3);

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IIPLDOTNETConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        myConnection.Open();
        string qy3 = "select count(*) from fb_customer where customer_fb_id='" + custid + "'";
        string count;
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(qy3, myConnection);
        SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            count = myReader[0].ToString();
            int cnt = Convert.ToInt32(count);
            if (cnt == 0)
            {
                SqlConnection myOleConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IIPLDOTNETConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                string qy = "select * from fb_customer";
                myOleConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand myOleCommand = new SqlCommand(qy, myOleConnection);
                myOleCommand.CommandText = "SET DATEFORMAT MDY insert into fb_customer(customer_fb_id,name,firstname,lastname,link,gender,cust_date,New) values('" + custid + "','" + name + "','" + fst_name + "','" + lst_name + "','" + link + "','" + gender + "','" + abctime + "','1')";
                SqlDataReader myOleDataReader = myOleCommand.ExecuteReader();
                myOleDataReader.Close();
                myOleConnection.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                SqlConnection myOleDb = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IIPLDOTNETConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                string qy1 = "select * from fb_customer";
                myOleDb.Open();
                SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(qy1, myOleDb);
                mycmd.CommandText = " UPDATE fb_customer set name='" + name + "',firstname='" + fst_name + "',lastname='" + lst_name + "',link='" + link + "',gender='" + gender + "',cust_date= '" + abctime + "' where customer_fb_id = '" + custid + "'";
                SqlDataReader mydatareader = mycmd.ExecuteReader();
                mydatareader.Close();
                myOleDb.Close();
            }
        }
        myReader.Close();
        myConnection.Close();

    }

    public void IIPLCustomer(string iiplcustid, string abctime)
    {
        var accessToken = "CAACEdEose0cBADKYiSkFVcqeZAYxmYlytKM5pQT6zuEvnNoU9soPlWc2pZAJvKDL557BKTGIRNhbcuZBR6Li8TlrcM8yG1yXYGzikVlUPyFgDPzEDMiIZAnuHe5y3gTZCxkyTeA12ISPPRhJev6B63rTr05slMfwZD";
        var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        string clientfeed = client.Get(iiplcustid).ToString();

        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(clientfeed);

        string custid = obj["id"].ToString();
        string name = obj["name"].ToString();
        string[] splitname = name.Split(' ');
        string link = obj["link"].ToString();           


        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IIPLDOTNETConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        myConnection.Open();
        string qy = "select count(*) from fb_customer where customer_fb_id='" + custid + "'";
        string count;
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(qy, myConnection);
        SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            count = myReader[0].ToString();
            int cnt = Convert.ToInt32(count);
            if (cnt == 0)
            {
                SqlConnection myConnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IIPLDOTNETConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                string qy1 = "select * from fb_customer";
                myConnection1.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(qy1, myConnection1);
                myCommand1.CommandText = "SET DATEFORMAT MDY insert into fb_customer(customer_fb_id,name,link,firstname,lastname,cust_date,New) values('" + custid + "','" + name + "','" + link + "','" + splitname[0] + "','" + splitname[1] + "','" + abctime + "','1')";
                SqlDataReader myReader1 = myCommand1.ExecuteReader();
                myReader1.Close();
                myConnection1.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                SqlConnection myOleDb = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IIPLDOTNETConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                string qy1 = "select * from fb_customer";
                myOleDb.Open();
                SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(qy1, myOleDb);
                mycmd.CommandText = "SET DATEFORMAT MDY UPDATE fb_customer set name='" + name + "',firstname='" + splitname[0] + "',lastname='" + splitname[1] + "',link='" + link + "',cust_date='" + abctime + "' where customer_fb_id = '" + custid + "'";

                //Here I'm getting an error
                SqlDataReader mydatareader = mycmd.ExecuteReader();
                mydatareader.Close();
                myOleDb.Close();
            }
        }
        myReader.Close();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `parameters` ?

Comment: Please, isolate the part of the code, that has the problem. Help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Datetime.ParseExact` method to convert date into appropriate format. Use like this

> DateTime.ParseExact('07-12-2013', 'dd/MM/yyyy',
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')

You need to change the format whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna be very simple. Try the following format.

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM");
```

I just gave DateTime.Now and converted it. You can give the DateTime which you get and convert it to the format specified in the above syntax.

Comment: i want to display the date in varchar format so how can i use varchar in date.now() ??